# EF6 code-first getting a undesired referenceID

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first-mapping

For some reason when generating my database I'm getting an unnecessary foreign key and I have no idea how to stop it.

A sample to replication this issue is as follow:

```cs
public class Person
{
   public int PersonId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<PersonRelationships> PersonRelationships { get; set; }
}

public class PersonRelationship
{
   public int PersonRelationshipId { get; set; }
   public Person PersonOne { get; set; }
   public Person PersonTwo { get; set; }
   public PersonRelationshipType RelationshipType { get; set; }
}

public enum PersonRelationshipType
{
   Mother = 1,
   Father = 2,
   Sibling = 3
}
```

In my `DbContext` I have:

```cs
DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
```

Now what's strange is when I generate the model with code first migrations, the `PeopleRelationships` table will get the expected foreign keys for `PersonOne_PersonId`, `PersonTwo_PersonId` but then an unexpected `Person_PersonId` will be there as well. I think it has something to do with the reference in the person but I'm not sure how to get rid of it since I need that reference.

What am I  missing?

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: That is the answer Steve. Inverse property fixed it. Fantastic thank you!

Comment: You should move this to an answer so I can mark it as answer!

Comment: No worries, little effort there. The fluent way should work as well if you hook up the FKs properly.

Answer (score 1):

Per Steve Greene's comment on the original post, the answer is to mark the inverse properties with the [InverseProperty("PropertyName")] attribute.

Thanks Steve!

Answer (score 0):

There are two foreing key from same table. I think you need to use `DbModelBuilder` to define your foreign keys and edit Person model like following. Then You can update your database.

```
public class Person
{
   public int PersonId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<PersonRelationships> PersonOneRelationships { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<PersonRelationships> PersonTwoRelationships { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PersonRelationship>()
                    .HasRequired(m => m.PersonOne )
                    .WithMany(t => t.PersonOneRelationships)
                    .HasForeignKey(m => m.PersonOneId)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PersonRelationship>()
                    .HasRequired(m => m.PersonTwo )
                    .WithMany(t => t.PersonTwoRelationships)
                    .HasForeignKey(m => m.PersonTwoId)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks hasan, when i did this is actually added an additional foreign key instead of removing the first.  so now it has two additional person_personid columns its trying to save

Comment: it did not. It made the problem worse.

Comment: Everytime we add a new ICollection to Person it adds a new person_id FK to the relationships table. It doesnt realize that the person objects it has are the actual references

Comment: can you try to re-create these two tables with this way

Comment: I manually did so, and when I try to save it throws an exception that the table does not contain a column person_id